# How to change the Google Places API - Place Autocomplete background color

Tags: android, google-places-api

Trying to change [The autocomplete service in the Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget)  search box color from green to white. look at the pictures below.

Going trough among all the [Google Places API Tutorial For Android](http://www.startingandroid.com/google-places-api-tutorial-for-android/) and I cannot find where to change the search box color from green to white.

I think the widget should inherit the parent activity styles. I run this inside of a Fragment maybe that's why it's green but undoubtedly. I don´t even have this green color in my styles/color xml.

Here´s the [github GooglePlacesApiTutorial](https://github.com/StartingAndroid/GooglePlacesApiTutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the current release of the Place Picker (it should pick up theme colors from the app, but doesn't). You can track the issue here https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7968